# Number of rows in table to integer

Tags: php, mysql, integer

I got some problems with PHP and MySQL. I'm trying to get a number of rows from table. Here is my code:

```
$quest=mysqli_query($link,"Select * From Friends");
$rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($quest);
printf("Result set has %d rows.\n",$rowcount);
$how_many=(int)$rowcount;

$how_many=$how_many+1;
echo $how_many;
```

And when I try to insert this value to table or show it just nothing happens.
HMMM after some time i tried this code and now it's working. Thanks for help :)

Comment: can you post your code that initializes $link?

Comment: You didn't check for any errors. Make use of [`mysqli_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) function.

Comment: link is only connction with my datebase on server

Comment: i want to use it to count rows and insert this data to tabel but when i tried its just nothing happend

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code with my local database using wamp server with PHP7 and it works fine.

```
<?php

$link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "blog_user", "", "Blog");

$quest=mysqli_query($link, "Select * From Articles");
$rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($quest);
printf("Result set has %d rows.\n",$rowcount);
$how_many=(int)$rowcount;

$how_many=$how_many+1;
echo $how_many;
?>
```

1) Make sure the connection to the DB works.
2) Display all SQL errors and PHP errors to localize the error.